# triangulatePoints() method gives wrong 3D coordinates

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, triangulation

triangulatePoints() method returns 4D coordinates as (X, Y, Z, W). Real object coordinates can be calculated as (X/W, Y/W, Z/W). I tried to plot points (chessboard corners) generated by this method before and after dividing by W. Interestingly, the correct location of points is only without dividing:

[image: without dividing by W]

But these coordinates are not real (the real distance between adjacent corners is 1)

After dividing:

[image: after divinding]

Definitely, there is something wrong

I think it can be caused by strange values of W:

```
[ 1.42646418e-03  1.22798549e-03  1.02968386e-03  8.39846092e-04
   6.36201818e-04  4.52465261e-04  2.69547454e-04  8.46875409e-05
  -9.68981258e-05  1.40832004e-03  1.21079874e-03  1.01654453e-03
   8.17881722e-04  6.27299945e-04  4.34311369e-04  2.59211694e-04
   8.54686004e-05 -8.65304610e-05  1.40546728e-03  1.20577158e-03
   1.01246696e-03  8.14260624e-04  6.32434676e-04  4.47672734e-04
   2.72056146e-04  9.63734783e-05 -8.87211063e-05  1.40579767e-03
   1.20654306e-03  1.01806328e-03  8.29431403e-04  6.48407149e-04
   4.67954233e-04  2.88052834e-04  1.05378487e-04 -8.11762657e-05
   1.42593682e-03  1.23078423e-03  1.04424497e-03  8.57530802e-04
   6.73743780e-04  4.87769896e-04  3.05575493e-04  1.14500137e-04
  -7.35641006e-05  1.46166584e-03  1.27260783e-03  1.07531622e-03
   8.86362221e-04  6.96056406e-04  5.09601785e-04  3.19138955e-04
   1.36194620e-04 -5.99504456e-05]
```

I feel that these values should be almost the same, but they differ by more than 2 orders. Where is a mistake?

Comment: what is "depth" in your 4d space? Typically, either x,y,depth  are given (depth camera, x,y are pixel coordinates) or X,Y,Z in 3D

Comment: yea, it's my term mistake, in literature it's called W value, and 3-dimensional coordinates are found as (X/W, Y/W, Z/W) ("Learning OpenCV 3 ...", Kaehler A, Bradski G). But the problem remains...

Comment: but if you dont divide the values by W the result is good? Maybe W is meant to be something different (reconstruction error?) But according to the docs, points are given in homogeneous coordinates, so dividing by W in theory would be right ...

Comment: Yes, without dividing the result is good and just wrongly scaled. It's easy to rescale coordinates manually such way that the distance between adjacent chessboard corners will be 1.0 but I would like to recognize what is W, and why the documentation doesn't correspond with this case